# Dimmed things in mod tools

Tags: feature-request, design

Is there a way to have the questions in the list of flagged things as shown in the mod tools *not* be dimmed unless the point is on them? That renders the page more or less unreadable using, say, my iPod Touch. In any case, it is simple too distracting even in my desktop computers.

In general, the fascination with `:hover` in these sites is quite unnerving! :)

Comment: Well, since I don't have a flags list I can look at I can't really divine the purpose of the dimming, but usually on these sites dimming signifies something.  Hopefully someone will chime in with that meaning.

Comment: Questions are dimmed in the mod queue when the moderator has already viewed them before.

Comment: @Robert, There are surely other ways to provide that information which do not turn most of the content in the page unreadable, and make the page behave like a video game!

Comment: I'm not a fan of the dimming, personally.